# how to set LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration once for whole project using java util logger?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, java.util.logging

In my project for every class having log messages like

**Logger.getLogger("LoggingExample.class").info("Logging an INFO-level message");**

- how to specify common LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration at
  one place instead of writing configuration for every file.
- For java util logger it is default logging.properties taking from
  java home directory i don't want to maintain properties file in java home directory i
  want to maintain it with in project folder how to do this in java util logger

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a logger every time. As java.util.Logger is thread safe, it is feasible to declare it only once and use it every time. Below is an example:

```
private static final Logger myLog = Logger.getLogger("loggerName");
myLog .warn("Text");
```

Best practice is to use one logger per class. And if it does not involve more efforts then, I would advise to use `log4j` framework.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to hold a [strong reference](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6274920) to a logger so you don't lose your configuration changes.  Here is a modified example taken from the [Java Logging Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html):

```
public class Nose {
// Obtain a suitable logger.
private static final String CLASS_NAME = Nose.class.getName();
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CLASS_NAME);
public static void main(String argv[]) {
    // Log a FINE tracing message
    logger.fine("doing stuff");
    try{
        Wombat.sneeze();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Log the exception
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "trouble sneezing", ex);
    }
    logger.fine("done");
}
```

}

If you want to use a custom configuration file you can specify the 'java.util.logging.config.file' system property to point to path of your properties file.  This is explained in detail in the [LogManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) documentation.